# How to create dynamic rounded corners in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Following is the code for creating rounded corners in javascript:

https://jsbin.com/weqolonuku/edit?html,js,output

I've implemented some maths to achieve this:

```js
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;

function angleBetweenLines(
  L1,
  L2,
  options = {
flip: false,
inDegrees: false,
  }
) {
  const dL1x = L1.x2 - L1.x1;
  const dL1y = L1.y2 - L1.y1;

  const dL2x = L2.x2 - L2.x1;
  const dL2y = L2.y2 - L2.y1;

  let angle = Math.atan2(dL1x * dL2y - dL1y * dL2x, dL1x * dL2x + dL1y * dL2y);

  if (angle < 0 && options.flip) {
angle = angle * -1;
  }

  return options.inDegrees ? angle * (180 / Math.PI) : angle;
}

 function degToRadians(degrees) {
  return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
}

const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: "container",
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);



const path = new Konva.Path({
  stroke: "black",
  strokeWidth: 1,
  data: `M 100 200 L 300 400`,
});

layer.add(path);

var arc = new Konva.Arc({
  x: stage.width() / 2,
  y: stage.height() / 2,
  innerRadius: 40,
  outerRadius: 70,
  angle: 50,
  fill: "yellow",
  stroke: "black",
  strokeWidth: 4,
});

const lsegment = new Konva.Line({
  stroke: "red",
});

layer.add(arc);
layer.add(lsegment);

addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  let p1 = { x: 300, y: 400 };
  let p2 = {
    x: e.offsetX,
    y: e.offsetY,
  };
  let p = {
    x: e.offsetX / 2,
    y: e.offsetY,
  };
  let radius = 10;

  let line1 = {
    x1: p1.x,
    y1: p1.y,
    x2: p.x,
    y2: p.y,
  };

  let line2 = {
    x2: p.x,
    y2: p.y,
    x1: p2.x,
    y1: p2.y,
  };

  const angle = angleBetweenLines(line1, line2, {
    flip: true,
    inDegrees: true,
  });

   let segment = radius / Math.abs(Math.tan(degToRadians(angle) / 2));
  const pp1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p.x - p1.x, 2) + Math.pow(p.y - p1.y, 2));
  const pp2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p.y - p2.y, 2));

  const min = Math.min(pp1, pp2);

  if (segment > min) {
    segment = min;
    radius = segment * Math.abs(Math.tan(degToRadians(angle) / 2));
  }

  const po = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(radius, 2) + Math.pow(segment, 2));

  const r = 10;

  const c1x = p.x - ((p.x - p1.x) * segment) / pp1;
  const c1y = p.y - ((p.y - p1.y) * segment) / pp1;
  const c2x = p.x - ((p.x - p2.x) * segment) / pp2;
  const c2y = p.y - ((p.y - p2.y) * segment) / pp2;

  const dx = p.x * 2 - c1x - c2x;
  const dy = p.y * 2 - c1y - c2y;

  const pc = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2));

  const ox = p.x - (dx * po) / pc;
  const oy = p.y - (dy * po) / pc;

  let startAngle = Math.atan((c1y - oy) / (c1x - ox));
  let endAngle = Math.atan((c2y - oy) / (c2x - ox));

  let sweepAngle = endAngle - startAngle;

  if (sweepAngle < 0) {
    sweepAngle = -sweepAngle;
    startAngle = endAngle;
  }

  if (sweepAngle > 180) sweepAngle = 180 - sweepAngle;

  lsegment.points([p.x, p.y, p.x + segment, p.y + segment]);

  arc.setAttr("angle", angle);

  console.log(segment);


  path.data(
    `M ${p1.x} ${p1.y} L ${c1x} ${c1y} C ${c1x} ${c1y}  ${p.x} ${p.y} ${c2x} ${c2y} L ${p2.x} ${p2.y}`
  );
  layer.draw();
});

layer.draw();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Konva demo">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@^3/konva.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

& also how to improve the above method?

Can someone suggest what am I missing?

This is getting off at some point (it is not appearing smooth)

[image]

**Also how to clamp the radius so that it won't grow beyond a certain range**

Comment: Stepping through your code using a debugger may help to see where things go crazy, you could set a conditional break point that triggers when your corner radius delta is too great. Setting up vscode or Chrome dev tools is my suggestion.

Comment: How can I step through each line? I've used the native debugger in the chrome... but not sure how to locate the spot. Actually there is no error here. I think I'm missing something. How can I locate that missing line/point through a debugger. I've nt used debugger that much for that kind of purpose.. (Cause I need to still locate the line which is causing the issue to setup a breakpoint & debug using chrome devtools). or is there a way to execute it line by line.

Comment: Debuggers can be powerful. Checkout [Get Started with Debugging JavaScript in Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript), specifically step 3 on setting breakpoints and step 4 on how to step through the code. You can set breakpoints wherever you want, place them where you'd like to investigate what each line of code is doing. I would set breakpoints at lines you are suspicious of. If you can isolate one value that is jumping too much, try a conditional breakpoint that triggers when the delta expression is too great, then checkout your variable values.

Comment: If it helps grow your perception of a debugger, I like to think of a debugger as a tool that can freeze your program in time and let you take a peak inside at what is happening. Some debuggers even let you step backwards in time!

Comment: But still you need to assume a breakpoint first.... right??

Comment: Here something else is the issue!!

Comment: You can put a breakpoint wherever you want. Maybe I'm missunderstaning your issue.